# Two player platformer game - gameover issue

Tags: unity, c#

I'm creating a two player platformer game but facing issues when one of the player dies. So far I have created two players and added the following script to both. The issue I'm facing is that once any of the players hits an obstacle, the dying animation and the gameover screen just keep on repeating. I think this is because I have the code to check if the player is dead in the update function of the gamemanager script. I would like the game to stop as soon as any player hits an obstacle and then the gameover screen should pop up.

```
public class Player: MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody { get; set; }  

public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

[SerializeField]
public Animator animator;

public bool isDead = true;

public GameManager gameManager;

public bool IsDead
{
    get
    {
        return isDead;
    }       
}

void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}   

void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !IsDead)
        {            
           jump = true;
           animator.SetBool("jump", true);
        }else
        {
           animator.SetBool("jump", false);
        }     
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (!isDead && collision.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        StartCoroutine(Die());
    }

}

public IEnumerator Die()
{
    isDead = true;
    animator.SetBool("Die", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);        
    gameManager.GameOver();

}

public void Jump()
{        
    myRigidbody.AddForce(jumpForce* Vector2.up, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

This is the gamemanager script:

```
public enum GameStates { Start, InGame, GameOver};

[SerializeField]
private Player player;

[SerializeField]
private Player player1;   

public GameObject startPanel, ingamePanel, gameoverPanel;   

void Update () {

    if(player.IsDead )
    {
        StartCoroutine(player.Die());
        GameOver();

    }

    if (player1.IsDead)
    {
        StartCoroutine(player1.Die());
        GameOver();
    }
}

public void GameOver()
{
    UpdateUI(GameStates.GameOver);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple solution, 
In Game Manager script, 
just add another Boolean “died”

Like so

```
bool died = false;
```

Then, in your game over code set `died = true;`

In your “if statements” in Update() add a check

```
&& !died
```

So your code will look like this

```
private bool died = false;

void Update () {

    if(player.IsDead && !died)
    {
        StartCoroutine(player.Die());
        GameOver();
    }

    if (player1.IsDead && !died)
    {
        StartCoroutine(player1.Die());
        GameOver();
    }
}

public void GameOver()
{
    died = true;
    UpdateUI(GameStates.GameOver);  
}
```

Comment: This will solve your problem , mark it as correct if you can .

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its working fine now....

Answer (score 0):

So to start off, you're exactly right about the cause of your problem.

You're creating Coroutines in `Update()` - you should try to avoid this.

Every time you create a Coroutine, imagine that you're creating an instance of your method and letting it run to the first yield command. On subsequent frames, it's going to run to the next and so forth. You can create one or as many of these routines as possible, they're each going to update to the next yield once per frame.

In `OnTriggerEnter2D()` you're creating an enumerator which sets the boolean value `isDead` to true. Then, in the same frame (or next frame) you'll create a new Coroutine in `Update()` method and do this again. And the next frame again. Even if we were to stop here, you'll have numerous coroutines being created every frame that wait two seconds before calling `GameOver` again.

This is going to be the root cause of your problem.

So as a general rule - don't create coroutines in `Update()`.

If you remove these from `Update()` you'll now be able to trigger death from `OnTriggerEnter2D()` - provided that it's being triggered correctly from the obstacle.